# SDL2/SDL.h not found, clang(pp_file_not_found)

Tags: c++, c++11, sdl-2, msys2, clangd

I don't understand where I'm making a mistake.
My steps:

1. Installing vscodium, msys2. Updating msys2 packages, installing clangd extension, CodeLLdb.
2. Checking compilation build, work.everything works.
3. Installing SDL inside the project.
   Tree - [Tree project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ueQ1R.png)
4. `с_cpp_properties.json`

   ```
   {
   "configurations": [
       {
           "name": "Win32",
           "includePath": ["${workspaceFolder}/**", 
                           "${workspaceFolder}/SDL2/include/**",
                           "${workspaceFolder}/SDL2/lib/**"
           ],
           "defines": [
               "_DEBUG",
               "UNICODE",
               "_UNICODE"
           ],
           "compilerPath": "C:\\msys64\\clang64\\bin\\clang++.exe",
           "cStandard": "c11",
           "cppStandard": "c++17",
           "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64"
       }
   ],
   "version": 4
   }
   ```
5. `launch.json`

   ```
    {
           // Use IntelliSense to understand related properties.
           // Hover to view the description of an existing property.
           // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
           "version": "0.2.0",
           "configurations": [
             {
               "name": "LLDB: Generate and debug order files",
               "type": "lldb",
               "request": "launch",
               "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\debug.exe",
               "args": [],
               "stopOnEntry": false,
               "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
               "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
               "environment": [],
               "externalConsole": false,
               "preLaunchTask": "Clang++: Compile single file"
             },
             {
               "name": "LLDB: Debug compiled debug.exe",
               "type": "lldb",
               "request": "launch",
               "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\debug",
               "args": [],
               "stopOnEntry": false,
               "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
               "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
               "environment": [],
               "externalConsole": false,
             }
           ]
         }
   ```
6. `settings.json`

   ```
   {
       "clangd.path": "clangd",
   }
   ```
7. `tasks.json`

   ```
   {
   "tasks": [
     {
       "type": "shell",
       "label": "Clang++: Compile single file",
       "command": "C:\\msys64\\clang64\\bin\\clang++.exe",
       "args": [
         "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.cpp",
         "-o",
         "debug.exe",
         "-g",
         "-Wall",
         "-Wextra",
         "-stdlib=libc++",
         "-std=c++20",
         "-I F:/Сode/Project/SDL2/include",
         /*"-I F:\\Сode\\Project\\SDL2\\include",*/
         "-L F:/Сode/Project/SDL2/lib",
         "-lmingw32",
                     "-lSDL2main",
                     "-lSDL2",
         "--target=x86_64-w64-mingw"
       ],
       "options": {
          "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
       },
       "problemMatcher": ["$gcc"],
       "group": {
         "kind": "build",
         "isDefault": true
       },
       "presentation": {
         "echo": true,
         "reveal": "always", 
         "focus": false, 
         "panel": "shared" 
       },
       "detail": "Clang++: Compile a single file"
     },
     ],
   "version": "2.0.0"
     }
   ```

```
Error `SDL2/SDL.h` not found, `clang(pp_file_not_found)`
```

I certainly read the workaround, in terms of installing packages `sdl2` in `msys2`. But I would like to understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Clangd needs `compile_commands.json` in the project directory to work properly. I don't think it respects `с_cpp_properties.json`.

Comment: HolyBlackCat
What should I write in compile_command.json? What was written in c_cpp_properties.json?

Comment: See https://clang.llvm.org/docs/JSONCompilationDatabase.html , or google the file name.